# Mangos-Zero project cannot find TBB

Tags: cmake, tbb

I'm trying to compile Mangos-Zero project on Windows.

I already have TBB installed, and set TBB_ROOT_DIR variable to:

```
C:\Users\Administrateur\Downloads\tbb-2018_U2\tbb-2018_U2
```

However, the project cannot find it:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:171 (message): This project requires TBB installed. Please download the TBB Stable Release from http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ and install it. If this script didn't find TBB and it was correctly installed please set TBB_ROOT_DIR to the correct path.
```

By looking into CMake variables set, I see ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsCzA.png)):

```
TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND
```

What can I do?

Comment: More info, please (what are you doing, precise error message and so).

Comment: Hello, I have this error message :

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:171 (message):
  This project requires TBB installed.  Please download the TBB Stable
  Release from http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ and install it.  If
  this script didn't find TBB and it was correctly installed please set
  TBB_ROOT_DIR to the correct path.`

I'm trying to compile Mangos-Zero project on Windows

Comment: But I have the the TBB_ROOT_DIR variable...

Comment: Where do you have TBB installed, and what is the value of `TBB_ROOT_DIR`?

Comment: Instead of posting information in the comments, [edit] the question and add this information into it.

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you very much for your help, you are awesome !

Comment: @Cylae: I have add more information from your comments into the question post. You write `TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND`, but on the screenshot this variable is set to normal value. So, how the screenshot is related to your problem?

Comment: How did you set `TBB_ROOT_DIR`? As environment variable or did you provide it as argument to your CMake call, e.g. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DTBB_ROOT_DIR=C:\Users\Administrateur\Downloads\tbb-2018_U2\tbb-2018_U2` ? This is relevant because the underlying CMakeLists.txt might not use the environment variables.